# migrating from google app engine with Groovy, Java and Gaelyk to another host

Tags: google-app-engine, groovy, gaelyk

I currently have an application that is built on gaelyk, groovy and GAE.

I would like to move this application as is to another host like Amazon EC2 and run it against MYSQL.  Is this possible?

I dont need the google USER services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/).

Comment: I have not personally used AppScale, but I've spoke with people who have had good luck with it.  I have used TyphoonAE ((http://code.google.com/p/typhoonae/) but it is Python only.

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on how you use App Engine currently with Gaelyk.
Gaelyk is syntax sugar on top of the GAE SDK, and builds upon of the shoulders of the Groovy giant: the Groovlet servlet and Template servlet are part of Groovy itself, not of Gaelyk.
So if you don't rely on the various GAE services, you can run your app on any Java container, wherever hosted it may be.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up migrating the app to grails which was easier than I thought.